# How to set angular material data table with pagination (data source) to the data array retrieved from the database using web-API

Tags: sql-server, angular, typescript, angular-material, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a web based application. I use Angular and Web API to develop the application, DBMS: SQL Server Management Studio 17.

I want to populate data which are stored inside my database in a Angular Material data table.

This is my customer-req-table-datasource.ts.

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

// TODO: Replace this with your own data model type
export interface CustomerReqTableItem {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: CustomerReqTableItem[] = [

  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
  {id: 10, name: 'Neon'},
  {id: 11, name: 'Sodium'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Magnesium'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Aluminum'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Silicon'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Phosphorus'},
  {id: 16, name: 'Sulfur'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Chlorine'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Argon'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Potassium'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Calcium'},
];
```

This is my customer.service.ts file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from './employee.model';
import { Customer } from './customer.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  formData: Customer;
  list: Customer[];
  readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:44300/api';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postCustomer(formData: Customer) {
   return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/Customer', formData);
  }

  refreshList() {
    this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/Customer').toPromise().then(res => this.list = res as Customer[]);
  }

  putCustomer(formData: Customer) {
    return this.http.put(this.rootURL + '/Customer/' + formData.CustomerID, formData);
   }

   deleteCustomer(id: number) {
     return this.http.delete(this.rootURL + '/Customer/' + id);
   }

}
```

**Problem:** How can I set the list [] array (in the service.ts file) data and populate the angular data table?

However, my final goal is to get the data inside the database and display those data using a angular data table.

Comment: FYI,"SQL Server Management Studio" is **not** the database engine version, its only a client interface. To get the database version try `select @@version`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way that can solve your problem. Now let us create a material table with the use of **mat-table**, **matColumnDef**, **matHeaderCellDef**, **matCellDef** and **matRowDef**.

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

We have the skeleton of the data table defined, now we have to provide data to it and the data is provided with the help of datasource and the name of the datasource we have already provided in [datasource] in mat-table. Now we will push data to the datasource in **app.component.ts** Following is the implementation.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(EXAMPLE_DATA);
}

export interface CustomerReqTableItem {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

const EXAMPLE_DATA: CustomerReqTableItem[] = [

  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'}
];
```

To enable pagination, angular provides **mat-paginator** directive that accepts the required parameter to perform pagination. This directive should be placed after the **mat-table** directive. But before using this directive, we need to import **MatPaginatorModule** in our material.module.ts.The following is an example.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="5" [pageSize]="3" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]">
  </mat-paginator>
```

Here, the length is the total no. of rows, pageSize is the no. of rows displayed in a single table view(default is 50) and pageSizeOptions enables the switching between the no. of rows displayed in a single table view.
Also, we need to configure the paginator in our .ts file to automatically listen for page changes made by the user after the page view is initiated.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
.
.
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```